# Cannot see IIS 8 express in visual studio 2013

Tags: .net

I installed IIS 8 express and can see it and run command line to start it.  But I cannot see it when right click on visual studio 2013 web project.  Should I see something like "Use IIS express"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install IIS express [using Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)